# python new instance not updating variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, instance

I'm trying to learn python with some data-structure. I'm trying to create a binary tree.

So I've created a node like:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value,left,right):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Then I've created a tree like:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = None

    def insert(self,node,element):
        if node == None:
            node = Node(element,None,None)
            return
        elif element <= node.value:
            self.insert(node.left, element)
        else:
            self.insert(node.right, element)
```

When I'm trying to insert `element` to the tree, it doesn't work. There is a stack call for that `insert` and the `node==None` is hitting and new `Node` is being created. But the `Tree` is not updating.

Comment: Did you mean to write `self.node = Node(element,None,None)`?

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
node = Node(element,None,None)
```

will create a method local variable, which is only visible in the scope of that method. Thus it will not affect the `Tree` instance in any way. To create an instance variable, use

```
self.node = Node(element,None,None)
```